# Replace curly braced wrapped expressions with hyperlinks in a string

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace, curly-braces

I'm struggling with some regex that can replace some formatted expressions in news articles that I get from an API:

I'm have a long string that consists of some content. Within the content there are brackets (`{}`) that contain a certain company and their company entity number -- I'd like to convert these to hyperlinks.

Input:

```
{Company X Inc.|CVR-1-81287283} was recently acquired by {Company Z Inc.|CVR-1-34251568}
```

Desired Output:

```
<a href="companies/CVR-1-81287283">Company X Inc.</a> was recently acquired by <a href="companies/CVR-1-34251568">Company Z Inc.</a>
```

Comment: what have you researched or tried so far? This isn't a free write-my-code service. We'll help you once you've shown some effort of your own and encountered a specific issue or question in your code. Have you looked into string replacement, or regular expressions, or other parsing techniques?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! No, I wasn't expecting you to write my code for me, but to maybe direct me in the right direction, as I am a bit blank a the moment. 

I have looked into string replacement, but as you can see, there are differences between the entities that has to be replace, therefore I don't think that string replacement will to right out of the box. 

Furthermore I have looked into regex, but I'm not skilled enough yet to see how I can say that I want this part of this specific string to put here and this there. 

Are there other possibilities that I haven't explored yet?

Comment: No problem. We just get a lot of "please do my homework for me" type questions here, from freeloaders. Normally it's best to state precisely what you want help with, then it doesn't just look like you're dumping all your requirements and expecting someone else to solve it all for you, for free. Perception is a powerful thing. Anyway, I would maybe use regex just like a parser, to extract the necessary bits of data from the string, and then write some separate PHP to generate the new version of it using those elements. I think using regex replacement directly would probably be tricky.

Comment: I'm new at writing questions here - sorry about my approach. I will look into doing that. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No worries. If you get stuck on the specifics of the code, that would make a good question to ask once you've written some, if you still have a bug or whatever. P.S. there's a helpful guide here on the site which explains how to write good-quality and well-received questions: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a format of

```
 { Company name | Company code}
```

You can make a regex that is split up into 2 parts just like the above format like below:

```
/\{([^\|]+)\|([^}]+)\}/
    ------   -------
  match       match
  company     company
  name        code
```

You might see a `\` before `{` or `|` or `}`. This is jut to escape regex metacharacters.
We basically match all characters that aren't a `|` for company name and all characters till `}` for company code.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = '{Company X Inc.|CVR-1-81287283} was recently acquired by {Company Z Inc.|CVR-1-34251568}';

preg_match_all('/\{([^\|]+)\|([^}]+)\}/',$str,$matches);

$result = sprintf('<a href="companies/%s">%s</a>  was recently acquired by <a href="companies/%s">%s</a>',$matches[2][0],$matches[1][0],$matches[2][1],$matches[1][1]);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` is all that you need to generate the desired output.  Anything beyond that is working too hard.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VGZnM))

```
$string = '{Company X Inc.|CVR-1-81287283} was recently acquired by {Company Z Inc.|CVR-1-34251568}';

var_export(
    preg_replace('~\{([^|]+)\|([^}]+)}~', '<a href="companies/$2">$1</a>', $string)
);
```

Output:  (you won't see the outermost single quotes if you use `echo` instead of `var_export()`)

```
'<a href="companies/CVR-1-81287283">Company X Inc.</a> was recently acquired by <a href="companies/CVR-1-34251568">Company Z Inc.</a>'
```

Pattern:

```
\{         #match a literal left curly brace
(          #start capture group #1
  [^|]+    #match one or more non-pipe characters
)          #end capture group #1
\|         #match a literal pipe
(          #start capture group #2
  [^}]+    #match one or more non-right-curly-braces
)          #end capture group #2
}          #match a literal right curly braces
```